# How to update the child table

Tags: database

I am currently struggling through my first magento project and it seems to be leaving me with asking more questions than it has answered.

My current hurdle is adding default data to a child table.

I have two tables **user** and **preferences** I have created these by adding them directly to the database (for simplicity sake)

My plan is that when a user is added to the user table, then the preferences are all automatically set (for them to edit at a later time).

So far I have learnt how to add data to a table, but i'm struggling with:

1. As I am using more than one table should I use Magento's EAV way creating tables?
2. If simply adding two separate tables is acceptable how do I update the preferences table when the user table has been added to?
3. To keep with best practices where should my code go for adding to a table and extracting from a table (helpers, models etc...)?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I added the prefcentreoptions node and table to my config

```
        <prefcentre_resource>
            <class>Ps_Prefcentre_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <prefcentre>
                    <table>prefcentre</table>
                </prefcentre>
                <prefcentreoptions>
                    <table>prefcentreoptions</table>
                </prefcentreoptions>
            </entities>
        </prefcentre_resource>
```

I added prefcentreoptions.php to the model folder

I added prefcentreoptions.php to the resource folder

I added a prefcentreoptions folder in the resource folder and added collection.php to that

I then tried to use

```
$prefs = Mage::getModel('prefcentreoptions/prefcentreoptions');

$prefs->setData('prefcentre_id', 1);
```

An error was thrown saying

```
Call to a member function setData() on a non-object
```

What have I done wrong

**EDIT**

After changing

```
$prefs = Mage::getModel('prefcentreoptions/prefcentreoptions');
```

to

```
$prefs = Mage::getModel('prefcentre/prefcentreoptions');
```

the script move onto another error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in /Users/myname/Sites/magentoDevTest/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 313
```

what information have I not provided to the script for it to continue?

(just incase it makes a difference)

The database i am writing to only requires one column to be completed the rest of the information will have default values which will be added

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons why the model is not found:

- `Mage::getModel('prefcentreoptions/prefcentreoptions')` is wrong, the parameter is badly formatted. Suppose that you have the following config.xml:

> ```
> <config>
> <global>
>     <models>
>         <pref>
>             <class>Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Model</class>
>         </pref>
>     </models>
> </global>
> </config>
> ```

And your class is located to `Mynamespace/Mymodulename/Model/Prefcentroptions` and its name is `Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Model_Prefcentroptions`
To get the model via Magento API, you will have to do `Mage::getModel('pref/prefcentroptions');`

- The class doesn't exist or badly located or defined into the config.xml file. It depends of your namespace and module name but the class name should be something like `Mynamespace_Mymodulename_Model_Prefcentroptions` and should be located to `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodulename/Model/Prefcentroptions`
- If you want to use `Mage::getModel('prefcentreoptions/prefcentreoptions')`, in config.xml you should have the tag under `models` equal to `prefcentreoptions`. `prefcentreoptions` is the group name found in the config.xml to identitfy the class base name like the following:

> ```
> <config>
> <global>
>     <models>
>         <prefcentreoptions>
>             <class>Mynamespace_Pref_Model</class>
>         </prefcentreoptions>
>     </models>
> </global>
> </config>
> ```

Then when you do `Mage::getModel('prefcentreoptions/prefcentreoptions')`, it will be translated to `Mynamespace_Pref_Model_Prefcentreoptions`

Comment: Thankyou for your help, but I have now got a new error which I have added to the questions, I hope you wouldn't mid giving your thoughts?

Comment: hi, this may help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics You may have forgotten `protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('groupname/tablename');
    }`